# django how to use exists()

Tags: django, django-queryset, exists

The django docs have the following:

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=123)
if some_queryset.filter(pk=entry.pk).exists():
   print("Entry contained in queryset")
```

could someone explain how this works?  does the first line have to be executed?  can we just do:

```
if some_queryset.filter(pk=123).exists():
    print("Entry contained in queryset")
```

I'm confused by what some_queryset is. In the above example wouldn't:

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=123)
if entry.filter(pk=entry.pk).exists():
   print("Entry contained in queryset")
```

make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we just do:
>
> ```
> if some_queryset.filter(pk=123).exists():
>     print("Entry contained in queryset")
> ```

**Yes**. The Django documentation only uses the example to fetch the `Entry` first to demonstrate that the `Entry` with `pk=123` exists in the `Entry` records. If you then want to check if it also exists in the `some_queryset` (which is for example a `.filter(…)`ed version of `Entry.objects.all()`), you can work with `.filter(pk=entry.pk)`.

But you do *not* need to fetch the `Entry` object first, if you somehow know the primary key in advance, you can already work with it directly. After all `entry.pk` is simply `123`, and it does not matter what the origin of that data is for the `.filter()` clause.

> I'm confused by what some_queryset is.

The idea is that they here have a `some_queryset`, which is a `QuerySet` over `Entry` objects. This can for example be an `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010)`, so a queryset that is filtered. If you then want to know if the `entry` is a member of this *filtered* queryset, you can use `some_queryset.filter(pk=123).exists()` to check if an `Entry` with `pk=123` is a member of this queryset. In this specific case (with `pub_date__year=2010`), we thus check if that `Entry` belongs to `Entry`s published in 2010.

Comment: so in this example is some_queryset = entry i.e. if entry.filter(pk=entry.pk).exists():

Comment: @DCR: `some_queryset` can not be `entry`. `Entry` is an `Entry` object, not a `QuerySet` of `Entry`s. `some_queryset` can be for example `Entry.objects.all()`, or `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010)`.

Comment: I don't understand.  Beginning to wonder if django is worth the time.  entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=123), isn't entry a queryset?

Comment: @DCR: no, `.get(..)` will retrieve a *single* record, and thus produce an `Entry`. If you use `Entry.objects.filter(pk=123)`, then you get a `QuerySet` (so with `.filter(...)`), but then of course it has no `.pk`, since a `QuerySet` is a (lazy) *collection* of objects.

Comment: how the heck do you run a filter on some_queryset that's not declared or defined?

Comment: I mean really could they make the documentation more obtuse

Comment: @DCR: the idea is that they provide an example, and here `some_queryset` is an arbitrary `QuerySet`, it can be anything.